# How can I get a column value from previous row in Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I want to get a value from the previous row.

I tried the following code as suggested in [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5577b086-1d84-4b7e-9bed-59f15b01a8b0/how-can-i-do-calculation-based-on-nextprior-row-in-power-query?forum=powerquery):

```
Table.AddColumn(#"Added index", "custom column", each {[Index]-1}[column name])
```

But it throws this error:

```
Cannot use field access fot type List
```

Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error comes because `{[Index]-1}` without anything before it is a list value, but instead you want to index into a row of a table with this syntax: `MyTable{index}`

That looks like:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Added index", "custom column", each #"Added index"{[Index]-1}[My Column])
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfectly sense!