# How can I refer a column value from previous row of the same column in Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I need to perform calculations in Power query which I already did in excel sheet. In one of the formulas I'm referring to cell just above it. For instance,
cell F45 = cell A1 + cell F44.

I tired to follow the steps as in [How can I get a column value from previous row in Power Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44053365/how-can-i-get-a-column-value-from-previous-row-in-power-query) i.e by creating an index field

But the solution doesn't work if the referring column and the output column in same as in my case. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the column it's best to add the new column, remove the old column, and then rename the new column to the old column's name.